# How to use JProgressBar as password strength meter,it should change color and value as I type

Tags: java, swing, interactive, swingworker

I am developing the logic to build a good password strength checker for my login form,but the problem is how to express strength of password entered ? I am using java and I am using this approach:

1. using JProgressBar as strength meter,it changes color when focus from JPasswordField is lost or when a key is released in JPasswordField (this gives quicker response).
2. Can I use Swing Worker on this to make it better ? I have never used it so can anybody help me with that if it is best way.

Please forgive me for long sentences.

See Image below:

---

[image: This image below shows what I want to achieve]

Comment: If you don't have a long-running background task, I see no need to use a SwingWorker. Do any of your methods seem to visibly slow or freeze your GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) doesn't make me sence in this case, that's just and about [DocumentListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

NOTICE: this example not about How to check password strenght, just how to listening for changes from [JPasswordField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) and redirect output to the [JProgressBar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)

[image][image][image]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class TextLabelMirror {

    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPasswordField field = new JPasswordField(20);
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private JLabel labelLength = new JLabel();
    private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 20);

    public TextLabelMirror() {
        field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLabel(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLabel(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLabel(e);
            }

            private void updateLabel(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = field.getText();//just example getText() is Depreciated !!!
                label.setText(text);
                labelLength.setText(" Psw Lenght -> " + text.length());
                if (text.length() < 1) {
                    progressBar.setValue(0);
                } else {
                    progressBar.setValue(text.length());
                }
            }
        });
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 0, 10, 0));
        mainPanel.add(field);
        mainPanel.add(label);
        mainPanel.add(labelLength);
        mainPanel.add(progressBar);
    }

    public JComponent getComponent() {
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Password Strength Checker");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TextLabelMirror().getComponent());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I made similar code as yours at the same time, but with focus listener and color change. I like your DocumentListener better though. 1+

Answer (score 3):

Same idea as mKorbel, but with color:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PasswordChecker extends JPanel {
   private static final Color[] PB_COLORS = {Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.green};
   private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 15;
   private JPasswordField pwField1 = new JPasswordField(10);
   private JPasswordField pwField2 = new JPasswordField(10);
   private JProgressBar progBar = new JProgressBar();
   private int ins = 10;

   public PasswordChecker() {
      pwField1.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
         public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            pwField1FocusLost(e);
         }
      });

      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 10,
               GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 
               new Insets(ins, ins, ins, ins), 0, 0);
      add(new JLabel("Password"), gbc);

      gbc = new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 10,
               GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, 
               new Insets(ins, ins, ins, ins), 0, 0);
      add(pwField1, gbc);

      gbc = new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 10,
               GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 
               new Insets(ins, ins, ins, ins), 0, 0);
      add(new JLabel("Confirm Password"), gbc);

      gbc = new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 10,
               GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, 
               new Insets(ins, ins, ins, ins), 0, 0);
      add(pwField2, gbc);

      gbc = new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, 1.0, 10,
               GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 
               new Insets(ins, ins, ins, ins), 0, 0);
      add(new JLabel("Strength"), gbc);

      gbc = new GridBagConstraints(1, 2, 1, 1, 1.0, 10,
               GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 
               new Insets(ins, ins, ins, ins), 0, 0);
      add(progBar, gbc);
   }

   private void pwField1FocusLost(FocusEvent e) {
      // simple check, just checks length
      char[] pw = pwField1.getPassword();
      int value = (pw.length * 100) / MAX_LENGTH;
      value = (value > 100) ? 100 : value;
      progBar.setValue(value);

      int colorIndex = (PB_COLORS.length * value) / 100;
      progBar.setForeground(PB_COLORS[colorIndex]);
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Password Checker");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new PasswordChecker());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: that I really appreciated by your person, GridBag + Colors + ... +1,